# Use Map to replace column values in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to map a list of columns to another column in a Spark dataset: think something like this

```scala
val translationMap: Map[Column, Column] = Map(
  lit("foo") -> lit("bar"),
  lit("baz") -> lit("bab")
)
```

And I have a dataframe like this one:

```
val df = Seq("foo", "baz").toDF("mov")
```

So I intend to perform the translation like this:

```
df.select(
  col("mov"),
  translationMap(col("mov"))
)
```

but this piece of code spits the following error

```
key not found: movs
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: movs
```

Is there a way to perform such translation without concatenating hundreds of `when`s? think that `translationMap` could have lots of pairs key-value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of `Map[Column, Column]` you should use a `Column` containing a map literal:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

val translationMap: Column = typedLit(Map(
  "foo" -> "bar",
  "baz" -> "bab"
))
```

The rest of your code can stay as-is:

```
df.select(
  col("mov"),
  translationMap(col("mov"))
).show
```

```
+---+---------------------------------------+
|mov|keys: [foo,baz], values: [bar,bab][mov]|
+---+---------------------------------------+
|foo|                                    bar|
|baz|                                    bab|
+---+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: By the way, how does this handle the case of an unknown key? for example, if I feed a column with a value different to `foo` or `baz` into `translationMap`? Ideally I'd like to return the unknown value unmodified

Comment: @mrbolichi, `coalesce(translationMap(col("mov")), col("mov"))` would handle non-matching keys the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can not refer a Scala collection declared on the driver like this inside a distributed dataframe. An alternative would be to use a UDF which will not be performance efficient if you have a large dataset since UDFs are not optimized by Spark.

```scala
val translationMap = Map( "foo" -> "bar" , "baz" -> "bab" )
val getTranslationValue = udf ((x: String)=>translationMap.getOrElse(x,null.asInstanceOf[String]) )
df.select(col("mov"), getTranslationValue($"mov").as("value")  ).show

//+---+-----+
//|mov|value|
//+---+-----+
//|foo|  bar|
//|baz|  bab|
//+---+-----+
```

Another solution would be to load the `Map` as a `DataSet[(String, String)]` and the join the two datasets taking `mov` as the key.

Comment: If possible, I'd rather avoid `udf`s because of the performance concerns you have mentioned. Also, this will be a very common operation so I'd like to avoid joins, since it would be convenient to have a function that will return a column to insert it into my `select`s

Comment: @philantrovert I am using the same but on cluster translationMap is coming as null , how to handle it ?  is it possible to send translationMap into UDF as parameter ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas