# how to update/transform/replace spark df column values using a hashmap

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, hashmap, transform

I want to replace the values of a given df column, using a hashmap but I am struggling with the syntax.
Can someone please point me in the right direction or to an existing example? I have searched but
not able to find something which sheds light on the exact subject.

**Edit**:

Imagine a dataframe like shown below:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+
|       Noun| Pronoun|  Adjective|
+-----------+--------+-----------+
|      Homer| Simpson|BeerDrinker|
|      Marge| Simpson|  Housewife|
|       Bart| Simpson|        Son|
|       Lisa| Simpson|   Daughter|
|TheSimpsons|Simpsons|     Family|
+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

And I have a map of key-value pairs like shown below:

```
  type ValueMap = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap [String,String]
  var mymap = new ValueMap ()
  mymap += ("Simpson" -> "Surname")
```

I want to do an operation (*which I am unable to figure out as of yet*) and achieve a result like shown below. So basically in the column `Pronoun`, all the column values which equal `Simpson` have been replaced by its corresponding value from the map `mymap` which is `Surname`

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+
|       Noun| Pronoun|  Adjective|
+-----------+--------+-----------+
|      Homer| Surname|BeerDrinker|
|      Marge| Surname|  Housewife|
|       Bart| Surname|        Son|
|       Lisa| Surname|   Daughter|
|TheSimpsons|Simpsons|     Family|
+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: can you clarify what means by replacing? maybe provide an example of what input data are, and what should be result

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, I have updated my program with an example. I hope that helps to highlight what I trying to go for.

Comment: I think that this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557771/use-map-to-replace-column-values-in-spark/56558406 (see the comment about for handling non-existing keys)

Comment: Hi @Alex: Thanks. Yes it does solve the problem. Unfortunately all the time I searched for "HashMap" and not "Map" - only if I had done that - I would have found the said post. Nevermind. Thanks for pointing out that to me. Much appreciated! Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this approach with UDF,

```
val myMap = Map("Simpson" -> "Surname")
val df = Seq(("Homer","Simpson","BeerDrinker"),("Marge","Simpson","Housewife"),("Bart","Simpson","Son"),("Lisa","Simpson","Daughter"),("TheSimpsons","Simpsons","Family")).toDF("Noun","Pronoun","Adjective")

df.show(false)

-----------+--------+-----------+
|Noun       |Pronoun |Adjective  |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
|Homer      |Simpson |BeerDrinker|
|Marge      |Simpson |Housewife  |
|Bart       |Simpson |Son        |
|Lisa       |Simpson |Daughter   |
|TheSimpsons|Simpsons|Family     |
+-----------+--------+-----------+

val getVal = udf((x: String) => myMap.getOrElse(x, x))
val resDF = df.withColumn("Pronoun", getVal($"Pronoun"))

resDF.show(false)

+-----------+--------+-----------+
|Noun       |Pronoun |Adjective  |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
|Homer      |Surname |BeerDrinker|
|Marge      |Surname |Housewife  |
|Bart       |Surname |Son        |
|Lisa       |Surname |Daughter   |
|TheSimpsons|Simpsons|Family     |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

Let me know if this helps.

> Updated:

Without UDF,

Added the map to DF as one more  column

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("map", typedLit(myMap))
val df2 = df1.withColumn("Pronoun", when($"map"($"Pronoun").isNotNull, $"map"($"Pronoun")).otherwise($"Pronoun") ).drop("map")
df2.show(false)

+-----------+--------+-----------+
|Noun       |Pronoun |Adjective  |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
|Homer      |Surname |BeerDrinker|
|Marge      |Surname |Housewife  |
|Bart       |Surname |Son        |
|Lisa       |Surname |Daughter   |
|TheSimpsons|Simpsons|Family     |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

> Another simple way instead of adding new column,

```
val colMap = typedLit(myMap)
val df3 = df.withColumn("Pronoun", when(colMap($"Pronoun").isNotNull, colMap($"Pronoun")).otherwise($"Pronoun") )
df3.show(false)
```

Comment: Hi, Is there no way to do it without the UDF ? The reason to not use UDF is that while running the spark cluster, it will not be touch and optimized by the catalyst optimizer.

Comment: Updated mt another approach without UDF

Comment: Hi @Sathiyan, The without UDF approach was just perfect. I believe that is what I may have been looking for. But unfortunately I couldn't make it work. And I know why (probably) - because I wasn't aware of "typeLit" and how it can be exploited in this case. Prior to this example I didn't know that one could convert a map to a column and use it in the shown manner. I thank you for your time and effort to help me solve my problem. I really appreciate that. Cheers!